# Android Blutooth two way data sending

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am developing application for Galaxy Gear,
I want to access data from note 3 application to galaxy gear application via Bluetooth.
Please can anyone give me sample application which demonstrate two way data sending between two devices using Bluetooth socket.